# how to represent an XML escape charecter in java String

Tags: java, xml, xsd

i am using an anyuri xsd data type. 
i am constructing it using java String builder.
now in order to comply with it i need to remove the char # from it and replace with an escape character.
now i tried replacing it with %23 which as i understand, is the hex representation of this char but to no a vile.
if any one encountered this issue please share.

Comment: It sounds like you're building XML. If so, use an XML API instead of StringBuilder. It'll save you a *lot* of heartache.

Comment: jon there is something to what your saying but what i am doing is a small piss of it.

Comment: @Chris there is no code i am trying to fine the right way to represent # in a string in such a way that it will be valid according to any uri definition.

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML you are receiving. The # does not need escaping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters

Answer (score 1):

You could use [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) to do that. This:

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("<some foo=\"xxx&\"/>"));
```

will output:

```
&lt;some foo=&quot;xxx&amp;&quot;/&gt;
```

But you should not go this route and just learn how to generate XML using a proper Java library. See some of the [java+xml questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+xml) around here.

**EDIT**
you can escape any unicode character by using &#xNN;, where NN is the hex value for the given char. # would be &#x23;

Comment: thanks but what i am doing is simulating a client side that sends this xml.  because the code is to big to change i cant take you advice and i did look over the questions but they don't touch what i need.

Comment: this looks a bit more like what i am looking for but what represents # in the same manner?

Comment: I think # doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: it does if you want it to comply with the any uri schame.

Comment: There is already escaping going on! So &amp; is an escaped &. You need to deactivate escaping in order to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

XML equivalent syntax, such as '<' is

> `&lt;`

Comment: @raven: No, &lt; stands for "less than" and is for escaping this char: <

Comment: @raven: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @raven: What I mean is that you should XML equivalent syntax instead of encoded URI string. For char '<', the XML equivalent syntax is just '&lt;'.